# ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit Combobox - Disallow insert of items

Tags: asp.net, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to use the new **combobox control** of the Ajax control Toolkit.
But I need it only for selecting an entry of a given list.
The user should not be able to insert own items into the list. How to prevent this?
The ItemInsertLocation seems to have no value to set this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Dropdownstyle should be 'DropDownList'
2. AutoCompleteMode should be set to 'Append' or 'SuggestAppend'